# Is it a good idea to place an apt-get update into bashrc

Tags: bash

I usually need to run `sudo apt-get update` before installing any dependencies I need, so would it be possible (or even harmful) to place one of those inside bashrc? I don't see it destroying anything major, but I just wanted to make sure before I went ahead and did it.

Comment: Would that not slow down the startup of interactive shells? Are you using `sudo` with a password? If yes, would you not get tired of typing that in just to start a terminal?  If no, what would happen if you start three terminals at once (does `apt-get update` properly handle concurrent invocations?)

Comment: Also, there are probably better options [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoWeeklyUpdateHowTo). Personally, I automatically download and manually install on my Debian box.

Comment: Hmm.. good points.  Thanks Sparhawk, I'll definitely check that out!

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to put 'apt(-get) update' into the .bashrc. Like Kusalandanda said, you will run into a couple of inconveniences/problems:

- apt(-get) update can only be started once, because it uses 1 lock-file
- it needs superuser privileges, thus you have to type in your password to open a new terminals
- as well you create unneccessary traffic (connecting the update server)

an appropriate way would be to call it via a cronjob.

Comment: Or just use the `apt-daily` service that comes in the apt package itself.